# How do I change the color of the unselected/normal segment text in an iOS 13 segmented controller?

Tags: uisegmentedcontrol, nsattributedstringkey

I am trying to configure an instance of the `UISegmentedController` class so that I can set the color of the text in the unselected segment from the default of black to white for a two-segment segmented controller. But I can't find any way of doing it. I have tried using the `setTitleTextAttributes(_,for:)`method but I cannot find a suitable `NSAttributedString.Key` attribute to change the text color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in a playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let seg = UISegmentedControl(items: ["foo", "bar"])
seg.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .normal)
seg.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue], for: .selected)
seg.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = seg
```